# Iterating over a tuple in Apache Spark

Tags: python, matrix, apache-spark, key-value

I have 2 matrix inputs that need to be multiplied with each other, I am trying to do that with map-reduce. So, I map them like this

```
def flatMapper( line ):
    tokens = line.split(' ')
    matrixName = str(tokens[0])
    row = int(tokens[1])
    column = int(tokens[2])
    value = int(tokens[3])
    if (matrixName == "A"):
        for i in range(0,5):
            yield((row, i), ("A", column, value))  // (row, i) is key and ("A", column, value) is column
    elif (matrixName == "B"):
        for i in range(0,5):
            yield((i, column),  ("B", row, value))
```

As it can be seen here, I produce more than one key-value pair for every line.

After this, I group them by key. Then for each key-value pair((i, j), ("matrixname", x, value)), I need to multiply the values such that their **x** are the same and **matrixname**'s are different, and sum all results, which is the value of (i, j)th element in matrix. So I need to write a reducer that iterates over a list of values for a given key, however I am stuck here. How can I iterate a list of values in my custom reducer function? (I tried this but it did not work)

```
result = result.reduceByKey(lambda k, v: reducer(k, v))
```

EDIT: I saw that actually flatMap successfully creates key-value pairs. I've used builtin function reduceByKey(add), which appended those list grouping by their keys. The problem here is, I can not write a custom reducer code since I can not iterate over keys with my custom function. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I will show you my approach for two vectors, represented by two different `RDD`. I think it's simpler than your attempt.

```
a = sc.parallelize([-1, 4, -2, 3])
b = sc.parallelize([-1, 2, 3, -2])

c = a.zip(b).map(lambda (x, y): x * y).sum()
```

The output will be `-3`, then you just have to amply the implementation for your matrix.